# Why is the size of vDSO region different across identical machines?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-memory

I have two identical machines with ASLR set to 0. They are running the same executable. The size of vDSO region is not the same across them. This causes other regions to shift. Why are the sizes not same?

Machine 1

```
00400000-00401000 r--p 00000000 ca:01 256227                             /home/ubuntu/pm/pm-pro
00401000-00482000 r-xp 00001000 ca:01 256227                             /home/ubuntu/pm/pm-pro
00482000-004a8000 r--p 00082000 ca:01 256227                             /home/ubuntu/pm/pm-pro
004a9000-004ac000 r--p 000a8000 ca:01 256227                             /home/ubuntu/pm/pm-pro
004ac000-004af000 rw-p 000ab000 ca:01 256227                             /home/ubuntu/pm/pm-pro
004af000-004d3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7ffff7ffa000-7ffff7ffd000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffff7ffd000-7ffff7fff000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
7ffffffde000-7ffffffff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

Machine 2

```
00400000-00401000 r--p 00000000 ca:01 293324                             /home/ubuntu/pm/pm-pro
00401000-00482000 r-xp 00001000 ca:01 293324                             /home/ubuntu/pm/pm-pro
00482000-004a8000 r--p 00082000 ca:01 293324                             /home/ubuntu/pm/pm-pro
004a9000-004ac000 r--p 000a8000 ca:01 293324                             /home/ubuntu/pm/pm-pro
004ac000-004af000 rw-p 000ab000 ca:01 293324                             /home/ubuntu/pm/pm-pro
004af000-004d3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7ffff7ffb000-7ffff7ffe000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffff7ffe000-7ffff7fff000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
7ffffffde000-7ffffffff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 --xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

Comment: I take it “identical machines” includes “identical kernel version”?

Comment: Yes. Two identical VMs.

Comment: How did you disable ASLR?

Comment: @StephenKitt Yes. Two identical VMs.

Comment: @bk2204 I've tried both methods given here https://askubuntu.com/a/318476/837196.